# Strange deserialization issue

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-deserialization

I've created classes from XSD Schema using xsd.exe (also tried with xsd2code which had better results in a way that they worked immediately, and with xsd.exe I have to debug some errors). XSD Schema I've used can be found at http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd , and sample file can be found at http://landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.1/samples/AASHTO%20SDMS/MntnRoad.xml .

My code for deserialization looks like:

```
var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (LandXML), new XmlRootAttribute(""));
TextReader myFileStream = new StreamReader("myFile.xml");
var myObject = (LandXML) mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

My problem is that result of deserialization is list of items of type XmlElement, so if I try to access their properties, I can't easy do that. If I want to access, for example, some Alignment object attribute in myFile.xml, the code is similar to this:

```
 var a = myObject.Items[5];
 var b = (XmlElement) a;
 var c = b.ChildNodes.Item(5).ChildNodes.Item(0).ChildNodes.Item(0).Attributes[0].Value;
```

It is obvious that this is not a way which is meant to be while deserializing XML to classes. My idea was like (for same element):

```
var c = LandXML.Alignments.Alignment.CoordGeometry.Curve.rot
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've tried with simpler schemas, and this code was working well. Please help and tnx in advance!

**EDIT 1**

this is at top of my class and I think that this List type generating troubles. And there is a more similar code in my generated classes

```
public class LandXML
    {

        private List<object> _items;

        private System.DateTime _date;

        private System.DateTime _time;

        private string _version;

        private string _language;

        private bool _readOnly;

        private int _landXMLId;

        private string _crc;

        public LandXML()
        {
            this._items = new List<object>();
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Alignments", typeof(Alignments))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Amendment", typeof(Amendment))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Application", typeof(Application))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CgPoints", typeof(CgPoints))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CoordinateSystem", typeof(CoordinateSystem))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FeatureDictionary", typeof(FeatureDictionary))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("GradeModel", typeof(GradeModel))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Monuments", typeof(Monuments))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Parcels", typeof(Parcels))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PipeNetworks", typeof(PipeNetworks))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PlanFeatures", typeof(PlanFeatures))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Project", typeof(Project))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Roadways", typeof(Roadways))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Surfaces", typeof(Surfaces))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Survey", typeof(Survey))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Units", typeof(Units))]
        public List<object> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this._items;
            }
            set
            {
                this._items = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LandXML));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            reader.Namespaces = false;
            LandXML landXML = (LandXML)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("LandXML")]
    public class LandXML
    {
        [XmlAttribute("version")]
        public double version  { get;set; }

        [XmlAttribute("date")]
        public DateTime date  { get;set; }

        [XmlAttribute("time")]
        public DateTime time { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("readOnly")]
        public Boolean readOnly  { get;set; }

        [XmlAttribute("language")]
        public string language  { get;set; }

        [XmlElement("Project")]
        public Project project { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("Units")]
        public Units units { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("Application")]
        public Application application { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("Alignments")]
        public Alignments alignments { get; set; } 
}
    [XmlRoot("Project")]
    public class Project
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name;
    }
    [XmlRoot("Units")]
    public class Units
    {
        [XmlElement("Imperial")]
        public Imperial imperial { get; set; } 
    }
    [XmlRoot("Application")]
    public class Application
    {
        [XmlElement("Author")]
        public Author author { get; set; } 
    }
    [XmlRoot("Imperial")]
    public class Imperial
    {
        [XmlAttribute("linearUnit")]
        public string linearUnit;

        [XmlAttribute("areaUnit")]
        public string areaUnit;

        [XmlAttribute("volumeUnit")]
        public string volumeUnit;

        [XmlAttribute("temperatureUnit")]
        public string temperaturUnit;

        [XmlAttribute("pressureUnit")]
        public string pressureUnit;

        [XmlAttribute("angularUnit")]
        public string angularUnit;

        [XmlAttribute("directionUnit")]
        public string name;
    }

    [XmlRoot("Author")]
    public class Author
    {
        [XmlAttribute("createdBy")]
        public string createdBy;

        [XmlAttribute("createdByEmail")]
        public string createdByEmail;

        [XmlAttribute("company")]
        public string company;

        [XmlAttribute("companyURL")]
        public string companyURL;

    }
    [XmlRoot("Alignments")]
    public class Alignments
    {
        [XmlAttribute("desc")]
        public string desc;

        [XmlElement("Alignment")]
        public Alignment alignment { get; set; } 

    }

    [XmlRoot("Alignment")]
    public class Alignment
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name;

        [XmlAttribute("desc")]
        public string desc;

        [XmlAttribute("length")]
        public string length;

        [XmlAttribute("staStart")]
        public string staStart;

        [XmlElement("AlignPIs")]
        public AlignPIs alignPIs { get; set; } 
    }
    [XmlRoot("AlignPIs")]
    public class AlignPIs
    {
        [XmlElement("AlignPI")]
        public List<AlignPI> alignPI { get; set; } 
    }

    [XmlRoot("AlignPI")]
    public class AlignPI
    {
        [XmlElement("PI")]
        public PI pi { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("InSpiral")]
        public InSpiral inSpiral { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("Curve1")]
        public Curve1 cureve1 { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("OutSpiral")]
        public OutSpiral outSpiral { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("Station")]
        public Station station { get; set; } 
    }

    [XmlRoot("Station")]
    public class Station
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot("PI")]
    public class PI
    {
        [XmlAttribute("code")]
        public int code;

        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public int name;

        [XmlText]
        public string value;
    }

    [XmlRoot("InSpiral")]
    public class InSpiral
    {
        [XmlElement("Spiral")]
        public Spiral spiral { get; set; } 

    }

    [XmlRoot("Spiral")]
    public class Spiral
    {
        [XmlAttribute("length")]
        public double length;

        [XmlAttribute("radiusEnd")]
        public double radiusEnd;

        [XmlAttribute("radiusStart")]
        public double radiusStart;

        [XmlAttribute("rot")]
        public string rot;

        [XmlAttribute("spiType")]
        public string spiType;
    }

    [XmlRoot("Curve1")]
    public class Curve1
    {
        [XmlElement("Curve")]
        public Curve curve { get; set; } 
    }

    [XmlRoot("Curve")]
    public class Curve
    {
        [XmlAttribute("rot")]
        public string rot;

        [XmlAttribute("radius")]
        public double radius;
    }
    [XmlRoot("OutSpiral")]
    public class OutSpiral
    {
        [XmlElement("Spiral")]
        public Spiral spiral { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for help, but that doesn't work - actually it does work, but my generated class file is over 30k lines of code and this is a huge job to change manually all of this. Main problem here is that I have List<object> where are stored other objects (like Alignment) and I can't access them directly as I can if I change strucutre to looks like your

Comment: I added EDIT 1 to better describe problem

Comment: An xml file can only have one root tag.  You have an array at the root level.  Changing conformance level may work.  Never used it with de-serialization.            string FILENAME = "";
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);

Comment: Then you need to add a root element that isn't an array.

Comment: @Rade I think jdweng is correct with this answer.  But It shouldnt be as much work as you are thinking.  You already made all the classes so you just need to take the items and break them into separate properties.  If you think its still too much, write a small program to do it for you or use regex's to do most of the replacements and then fix up any errors they created.